# Undo all files within a folder in git

Tags: git, git-commit, git-checkout, git-reset

I searched and found many link which talks about un-doing your uncommited changes with respect to specific file:

1. git reset
2. git reset --hard
3. git checkout -- file
4. git checkout branchname^ filename

**but I want to undo changes for all the files I have modifies under a specific folder.**

assume I have a folder like this `clients/libs/slickgrid` & `slickgrid` internally contains multiple folder which contains multiple files.

I want to undo all modified files under slickgrid folder. What options I have over here?

Answer (score 0):

`git reset HEAD clients/lib/slickgrid`

if they are already part of git's history you also then have to do

`git checkout clients/lib/slickgrid`

Comment: I have not commited the files so far :  running   `git checkout clients/lib/slickgrid`  gives `error: pathspec 'clients/lib/slickgrid' did not match any file(s) known to git.`    If I run `git reset HEAD clients/lib/slickgrid` and then run `git status` I can still see all the files

Comment: if there is nothing to checkout of git then you haven't changed files that are being tracked. run `git status` you'll see that git specifies those files are untracked. You will see
 `Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 foo.js` assuming your file untracked is foo.js. if they are not tracked then there is no way to revert changes. Does that make sense?